# How to understand "and" here

Tags: ambiguity, conjunctions, coordinating-conjunctions, disambiguation

I come across following [statement](https://intel.github.io/hyperscan/dev-reference/api_files.html?highlight=hs_flag_som_leftmost#c.HS_FLAG_SOM_LEFTMOST):

> Enabling this behaviour may reduce performance and increase stream state requirements in streaming mode.

I am confused with "reduce performance" is in parallel with "increase stream state requirements in streaming mode", or "increase stream state requirements".

If "reduce performance" is in parallel with "increase stream state requirements in streaming mode", it means "reduce performance" can occur in any mode, not only streaming mode.

If "reduce performance" is in parallel with "increase stream state requirements", it means "reduce performance" only occur in streaming mode.

Which one is correct?

Comment: It's not possible to determine from the sentence alone (or the docs you referenced). It could be grouped ((bad-thing-1 and bad-thing-2) in certain-mode), or ((bad-thing-1) and (bad-thing-2-in-streaming-mode)). I'd ask your specific concerns in an appropriate support board, so you get a definitive answer.

Comment: The sentence is ambiguous as written. The phrase "in streaming mode" might apply only to "increase stream state requirements" or it might apply both to that phrase and to "reduce performance." However, the fact that the lead-in word "may" applies to both of those phrases suggests to me that the writer may also have intended "in streaming mode" to apply to both. If so, the writer would have done future readers a big favor by recasting the sentence as "Enabling this behaviour in streaming mode may reduce performance and increase stream state requirements."

Comment: //Enabling this behaviour may reduce performance and increase stream state requirements in streaming mode.// A comma after performance can disambiguate it. That way ...in streaming mode goes with the second part alone.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a few issues here.

The way I read this, it could be re-written “enabling this behavior while in streaming mode can result in both reduced performance and increased stream state requirements “

But i think you are making a big logical error in concluding what you do in your final sentence.  It does not imply at all that the only in streaming mode can performance be reduced.

Answer (score 0):

> Enabling this behaviour may reduce performance and increase stream
> state requirements in streaming mode.

The 'natural' way to read this as an English statement is:

*Enabling this behaviour may*

*(a) reduce performance and*

*(b) increase stream state requirements in streaming mode.*

That also appears to make sense as a technical explanation. Performance is reduced in 'working' mode and state requirements are increased in 'streaming' mode.

However, without learning about this software in detail, **it is impossible to say** whether that is what is intended - the grammar alone is not sufficient. Very often the only way to distinguish meaning in ordinary English is from understanding the *context*.  This example is written in ordinary English with a couple of technical terms thrown in.

My advice is keep reading. Once you understand everything else, this will make sense. If it does not then ask on a specialist forum, not an English-language one.